# Expression Blend: Why do I not have options for Transitions and Easing?

Tags: expression-blend, transition, easing

I am using Expression Blend 4 with .Net 3.5

In the image below, there are options for Transition Effects and the ability to choose Easing effects for your transitions:

[image: Expression Blend States - With Effects and Transitions]

My Blend interface does not have these on my WPF application:

[image: Expression Blend States - NO Effects or Transitions Options]

However, if I create a new application (such as a WPF Sketchflow app) these options appear just as they do in the first photo.

What determines whether or not these options appear, and how can I get them into my WPF application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the WPF toolkit to even get this far with .NET 3.5.  (WPF 3.5 lacks the VisualStateManager; the toolkit adds this missing piece.)  As to why it doesn't show up, it's because it's [not supported in WPF 3.5](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ff624123):

> In V3, we added four primary enhancements in this area. The first was
>   EasingFunctions, which are critical to making property animations have
>   the right feel. We’ve got all the classics—quadratics, cubics, bounce,
>   elastic, etc. Plus, you can write your own EasingFunction in C# or VB
>   and apply it to any animation you wish. This is all supported in
>   Silverlight 3 and WPF 4.

When you create a new WPF Sketchflow app, it's almost certainly targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was afraid that it had something to do with .NET 3.5.  Our main application is being developed in 3.5, but I'm doing mockups and prototypes in Sketchflow using 4.0.  Hopefully, we'll be upgrading our development platform sometime soon :)