# Where is the Transition Effects button (fx) in Blend 2017?

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

In Blend 2012, there is a button for Transition Effects when changing visual states...

[image]

Where can I see this in Blend 2017?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a way, this is related to [Expression Blend: Why do I not have options for Transitions and Easing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125644/expression-blend-why-do-i-not-have-options-for-transitions-and-easing)

Blend 2012's default target framework is .NET 4.5. Blend 2017 is 4.5.2. Not sure why the button disappears on a higher version (4.5.2 and above).