# State transition effect missing in Blend 2015

Tags: wpf, xaml, effects, blend

In all videos I have seen there should be a fx button in Blend, allowing one to change between different types of transition effects. Question is simple, where is it? Do I need to do something special to enable it in Blend?

Please see a screenshot below how it looks. Where I have painted fx in red there should be a fx button.

I am working in a WPF project.

[image]

Comment: Are you using .Net 3.5? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125644/expression-blend-why-do-i-not-have-options-for-transitions-and-easing

Comment: @DipenShah no I targeting .Net 4.6.1. The problem in the link you sent seems to be if one target .Net 3.5 only. But maybe it is some namespace or reference missing indeed.

Comment: Also, are you creating a windows app or uwp app?

Comment: @DipenShah Windows App, but the current View I edit in Blend is in a WPF library project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that `States` window in Blend only shows *f*x when your project type is **WPF Application** or **WPF User Control Library**. When your are worling with **Class Library** project, states window does not display *f*x button for `VisualStateGroup`.

Only workaround is to create an new **WPF User Control Library** project.